# Orchestrator function code awaits on a task that was not created by a DurableOrchestrationContext method

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I have the following code in Orchestrator function:

```cs
var sourceGroups = await context.CallActivityAsync<AzureADGroup[]>(nameof(SourceGroupsReaderFunction), new SourceGroupsReaderRequest { SyncJob = syncJob, RunId = runId });
        
if (sourceGroups.Length == 0)
{
    await _log.LogMessageAsync(new LogMessage
    {
        RunId = runId,
        Message =
        $"None of the source groups in {syncJob.Query} were valid guids. Marking job as errored."
    });
    await _calculator.SendEmailAsync(syncJob, runId, SyncDisabledNoValidGroupIds, new[] { syncJob.Query });
}
```

On running this, I see the following error:

```
Function 'OrchestratorFunction (Orchestrator)' failed with an error. Reason: System.InvalidOperationException: Multithreaded execution was detected. This can happen if the orchestrator function code awaits on a task that was not created by a DurableOrchestrationContext method. More details can be found in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You must put await _calculator.SendEmailAsync(syncJob, runId, SyncDisabledNoValidGroupIds, new[] { syncJob.Query }); into activity. The reason is that orchestrators may execute multiple times from beggining and the activity functions are used to make sure it wont execute multiple times. Your code would potentially log or send emails multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! In order to make sure that messages are logged only one time from Orchestrator function, what should I do?

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168267/avoid-multiple-execution-in-orchestrator-function

Comment: To fix the loggning read answer from silent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171178/azure-durable-orchestration-function-ilogger-outputs-logs-twice/66171448#66171448